# Keeping the same selection color in a TableView whether it's active or not

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qstylesheet

I'm using QTableView class in my GUI and I would like the selected row to have the same color whether the TableView is active or inactive.
I tried to set this CSS stylesheet to achieve this:

```
QTableView:!active {
    selection-background-color: palette(Highlight);
    selection-color: palette(HighlightedText)
}
```

On Linux, it works just fine, but on Windows 7, when the TableView loses its focus, the text turns black instead of staying white (the background stays blue, so that part is OK). Am I missing something here ?

Comment: The [colors](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#paletterole) should be `palette(highlight)` and `palette(highlighted-text)`.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to style text color, for example just add:

```
QTableView:!active {
...
selection-color: white;
}
```

Comment: That's what I did as a workaround, but ekhumoro solution works too and I rather not hard code color in the stylesheet.

Comment: @Trap, great, I just use this simple approach to change to other color when the view is not in focus, that's a matter of whats the requirement :)

Answer (score 0):

This works well in python

```
pal = tbl_list.palette()
pal.setColor(QPalette.Inactive, QPalette.Highlight, pal.color(QPalette.Active, QPalette.Highlight))
tbl_list.setPalette(pal)
```

Comment: I can't edit because some mysterious edit queue is full: To also make the text use the appropriate color, duplicate the `setColor` line and use `HighlightedText` instead of `Highlight`. For reference: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpalette.html#ColorRole-enum